# Openshift router high restart count?

Tags: openshift-origin

we've been configuring monitoring of our openshift origin cluster and noticed that when we `oc get pods --all-namespaces` that our router pods have a high (> 200) restart count over the past month.

```
NAMESPACE                         NAME                           READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
default                           router-2-kactc                 1/1       Running            231        23d
default                           router-2-liyxb                 1/1       Running            212        23d
```

**edit: I was able to track down logs just prior to the pod crashing**

```
fatal error: concurrent map read and map write

goroutine 44 [running]:
runtime.throw(0x38e04e0, 0x21)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:530 +0x90 fp=0xc820991238 sp=0xc820991220
runtime.mapaccess2(0x2820680, 0xc820650480, 0xc8202995c0, 0x317ca60, 0xc82078c750)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/hashmap.go:343 +0x5a fp=0xc820991280 sp=0xc820991238
reflect.mapaccess(0x2820680, 0xc820650480, 0xc8202995c0, 0xc820650480)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/hashmap.go:993 +0x35 fp=0xc8209912b0 sp=0xc820991280
reflect.Value.MapIndex(0x2820680, 0xc820206240, 0x95, 0x2828680, 0xc8202995c0, 0x98, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:1041 +0x14a fp=0xc820991338 sp=0xc8209912b0
text/template.(*state).walkRange(0xc8209918c0, 0x329f660, 0xc820206230, 0x99, 0xc820143e80)
    /usr/local/go/src/text/template/exec.go:327 +0x885 fp=0xc820991538 sp=0xc820991338
text/template.(*state).walk(0xc8209918c0, 0x329f660, 0xc820206230, 0x99, 0x7f161f2bd1b0, 0xc820143e80)
    /usr/local/go/src/text/template/exec.go:226 +0x264 fp=0xc820991680 sp=0xc820991538
text/template.(*state).walk(0xc8209918c0, 0x329f660, 0xc820206230, 0x99, 0x7f161f300540, 0xc8206484e0)
    /usr/local/go/src/text/template/exec.go:223 +0x6a1 fp=0xc8209917c8 sp=0xc820991680
text/template.(*Template).Execute(0xc82056ad40, 0x7f161f2b8370, 0xc820074378, 0x329f660, 0xc820206230, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/text/template/exec.go:178 +0x2a7 fp=0xc820991908 sp=0xc8209917c8
github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/router/template.(*templateRouter).writeConfig(0xc82064a340, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/router/template/router.go:283 +0x892 fp=0xc820991d48 sp=0xc820991908
github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/router/template.(*templateRouter).commitAndReload(0xc82064a340, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/router/template/router.go:231 +0x14d fp=0xc820991db0 sp=0xc820991d48
github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/router/template.(*templateRouter).(github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/router/template.commitAndReload)-fm(0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/router/template/router.go:157 +0x2e fp=0xc820991dd0 sp=0xc820991db0
github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/util/ratelimiter.(*RateLimitedFunction).handleOne(0xc820650390, 0x33272e0, 0xc820650390)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/util/ratelimiter/ratelimiter.go:49 +0x48 fp=0xc820991e08 sp=0xc820991dd0
github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/util/ratelimiter.(*RateLimitedFunction).RunUntil.func1()
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/util/ratelimiter/ratelimiter.go:42 +0x6a fp=0xc820991e50 sp=0xc820991e08
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/wait.JitterUntil.func1(0xc8204cfc10)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:66 +0x4b fp=0xc820991e80 sp=0xc820991e50
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/wait.JitterUntil(0xc8204cfc10, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc82005a540)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:67 +0x68 fp=0xc820991f40 sp=0xc820991e80
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/wait.Until(0xc8204cfc10, 0x0, 0xc82005a540)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:47 +0x3e fp=0xc820991f68 sp=0xc820991f40
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1998 +0x1 fp=0xc820991f70 sp=0xc820991f68
created by github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/util/ratelimiter.(*RateLimitedFunction).RunUntil
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/util/ratelimiter/ratelimiter.go:42 +0x7d

goroutine 1 [select (no cases), 129 minutes]:
github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/cmd/infra/router.(*TemplateRouterOptions).Run(0xc820079c80, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/cmd/infra/router/template.go:203 +0x85e
github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/cmd/infra/router.NewCommandTemplateRouter.func1(0xc8200f8600, 0x5b9a280, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/cmd/infra/router/template.go:111 +0x1ad
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0xc8200f8600, 0xc82005e140, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:572 +0x85a
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC(0xc8200f8600, 0xc8200f8600, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:662 +0x53f
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(0xc8200f8600, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:618 +0x2d
main.main()
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/cmd/openshift/openshift.go:27 +0x180

goroutine 17 [syscall, 129 minutes, locked to thread]:
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1998 +0x1

goroutine 19 [chan receive]:
github.com/golang/glog.(*loggingT).flushDaemon(0x5b72140)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/golang/glog/glog.go:879 +0x67
created by github.com/golang/glog.init.1
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/golang/glog/glog.go:410 +0x297

goroutine 9 [syscall, 9 minutes]:
os/signal.signal_recv(0x7f161f2b4050)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sigqueue.go:116 +0x132
os/signal.loop()
    /usr/local/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:22 +0x18
created by os/signal.init.1
    /usr/local/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:28 +0x37

goroutine 45 [select]:
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/cache.(*Reflector).watchHandler(0xc82041a0a0, 0x7f161f2d1d30, 0xc8208aabd0, 0xc820665bf0, 0xc8203f0060, 0xc82005ae40, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/cache/reflector.go:320 +0x13f7
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/cache.(*Reflector).ListAndWatch(0xc82041a0a0, 0xc82005ae40, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/cache/reflector.go:287 +0x125f
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/cache.(*Reflector).Run.func1()
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/cache/reflector.go:160 +0x2c
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/wait.JitterUntil.func1(0xc8203f5200)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:66 +0x4b
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/wait.JitterUntil(0xc8203f5200, 0x3b9aca00, 0x0, 0xc82005ae40)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:67 +0x68
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/wait.Until(0xc8203f5200, 0x3b9aca00, 0xc82005ae40)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:47 +0x3e
created by k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/cache.(*Reflector).Run
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/cache/reflector.go:160 +0x84

goroutine 46 [select]:
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/cache.(*Reflector).watchHandler(0xc82041a1e0, 0x7f161f2d1d30, 0xc8208aa450, 0xc8205cdc00, 0xc8208c2000, 0xc82005ae40, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/cache/reflector.go:320 +0x13f7
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/cache.(*Reflector).ListAndWatch(0xc82041a1e0, 0xc82005ae40, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/cache/reflector.go:287 +0x125f
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/cache.(*Reflector).Run.func1()
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/cache/reflector.go:160 +0x2c
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/wait.JitterUntil.func1(0xc8203f5260)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:66 +0x4b
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/wait.JitterUntil(0xc8203f5260, 0x3b9aca00, 0x0, 0xc82005ae40)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:67 +0x68
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/wait.Until(0xc8203f5260, 0x3b9aca00, 0xc82005ae40)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:47 +0x3e
created by k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/cache.(*Reflector).Run
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/cache/reflector.go:160 +0x84

goroutine 47 [runnable]:
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/wait.JitterUntil(0xc8203f52e0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc82005ae40)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:74 +0x13c
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/wait.Until(0xc8203f52e0, 0x0, 0xc82005ae40)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:47 +0x3e
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/wait.Forever(0xc8203f52e0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:41 +0x37
created by github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/router/controller.(*RouterController).Run
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/router/controller/controller.go:46 +0x1da

goroutine 48 [semacquire, 9 minutes]:
sync.runtime_Syncsemacquire(0xc8203e2418)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sema.go:241 +0x201
sync.(*Cond).Wait(0xc8203e2408)
    /usr/local/go/src/sync/cond.go:63 +0x9b
github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/client/cache.(*EventQueue).Pop(0xc8203e23f0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/client/cache/eventqueue.go:273 +0xd9
github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/router/controller/factory.(*RouterControllerFactory).Create.func1(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/router/controller/factory/factory.go:71 +0x42
github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/router/controller.(*RouterController).HandleEndpoints(0xc82064d540)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/router/controller/controller.go:91 +0x30
github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/router/controller.(*RouterController).HandleEndpoints-fm()
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/router/controller/controller.go:47 +0x20
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/wait.JitterUntil.func1(0xc8203f52f0)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:66 +0x4b
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/wait.JitterUntil(0xc8203f52f0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc82005ae40)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:67 +0x68
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/wait.Until(0xc8203f52f0, 0x0, 0xc82005ae40)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:47 +0x3e
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/wait.Forever(0xc8203f52f0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:41 +0x37
created by github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/router/controller.(*RouterController).Run
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/router/controller/controller.go:47 +0x239

goroutine 49 [chan receive, 9 minutes]:
github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/util/proc.StartReaper.func1()
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/util/proc/reaper.go:23 +0x193
created by github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/util/proc.StartReaper
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/util/proc/reaper.go:35 +0x79

goroutine 82 [select, 129 minutes, locked to thread]:
runtime.gopark(0x3e67cf8, 0xc820023f28, 0x3573d80, 0x6, 0x430218, 0x2)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:262 +0x163
runtime.selectgoImpl(0xc820023f28, 0x0, 0x18)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/select.go:392 +0xa67
runtime.selectgo(0xc820023f28)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/select.go:215 +0x12
runtime.ensureSigM.func1()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal1_unix.go:279 +0x358
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1998 +0x1

goroutine 2218 [IO wait]:
net.runtime_pollWait(0x7f161f2cd258, 0x72, 0xc82046e800)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:160 +0x60
net.(*pollDesc).Wait(0xc8204c3f00, 0x72, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:73 +0x3a
net.(*pollDesc).WaitRead(0xc8204c3f00, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:78 +0x36
net.(*netFD).Read(0xc8204c3ea0, 0xc82046e800, 0x400, 0x400, 0x0, 0x7f161f2b4028, 0xc82005e080)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:250 +0x23a
net.(*conn).Read(0xc820024288, 0xc82046e800, 0x400, 0x400, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/net.go:172 +0xe4
crypto/tls.(*block).readFromUntil(0xc8208aa360, 0x7f161f3005f8, 0xc820024288, 0x5, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/crypto/tls/conn.go:460 +0xcc
crypto/tls.(*Conn).readRecord(0xc820676300, 0x3e67e17, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/crypto/tls/conn.go:562 +0x2d1
crypto/tls.(*Conn).Read(0xc820676300, 0xc820840000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/crypto/tls/conn.go:939 +0x167
net/http.noteEOFReader.Read(0x7f161f3006b0, 0xc820676300, 0xc8207b1248, 0xc820840000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0xc820027800, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1683 +0x67
net/http.(*noteEOFReader).Read(0xc8209f0380, 0xc820840000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0xfc19b4, 0x0, 0x0)
    <autogenerated>:284 +0xd0
bufio.(*Reader).fill(0xc820979e60)
    /usr/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:97 +0x1e9
bufio.(*Reader).ReadSlice(0xc820979e60, 0xa, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:328 +0x21a
net/http/internal.readChunkLine(0xc820979e60, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/internal/chunked.go:110 +0x53
net/http/internal.(*chunkedReader).beginChunk(0xc8208aa3f0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/internal/chunked.go:47 +0x39
net/http/internal.(*chunkedReader).Read(0xc8208aa3f0, 0xc820151600, 0x200, 0x200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/internal/chunked.go:77 +0xb7
net/http.(*body).readLocked(0xc820860200, 0xc820151600, 0x200, 0x200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transfer.go:651 +0xa1
net/http.(*body).Read(0xc820860200, 0xc820151600, 0x200, 0x200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transfer.go:643 +0x110
net/http.(*bodyEOFSignal).Read(0xc820860280, 0xc820151600, 0x200, 0x200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1609 +0x26a
encoding/json.(*Decoder).refill(0xc8203924e0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/encoding/json/stream.go:152 +0x287
encoding/json.(*Decoder).readValue(0xc8203924e0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/encoding/json/stream.go:128 +0x413
encoding/json.(*Decoder).Decode(0xc8203924e0, 0x275c5c0, 0xc8208602c0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/encoding/json/stream.go:57 +0x159
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/watch/json.(*Decoder).Decode(0xc8208aa420, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/watch/json/decoder.go:50 +0xa5
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/watch.(*StreamWatcher).receive(0xc8208aa450)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/watch/iowatcher.go:93 +0x104
created by k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/watch.NewStreamWatcher
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/watch/iowatcher.go:60 +0xbf

goroutine 2243 [select]:
net/http.(*persistConn).readLoop(0xc820815ba0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1178 +0xd52
created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:853 +0x10a6

goroutine 2244 [select]:
net/http.(*persistConn).writeLoop(0xc820815ba0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1273 +0x472
created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:854 +0x10cb

goroutine 2220 [IO wait]:
net.runtime_pollWait(0x7f161f2cd198, 0x72, 0xc8209f6000)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:160 +0x60
net.(*pollDesc).Wait(0xc82054c4c0, 0x72, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:73 +0x3a
net.(*pollDesc).WaitRead(0xc82054c4c0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:78 +0x36
net.(*netFD).Read(0xc82054c460, 0xc8209f6000, 0x8000, 0x8000, 0x0, 0x7f161f2b4028, 0xc82005e080)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:250 +0x23a
net.(*conn).Read(0xc8200242d8, 0xc8209f6000, 0x8000, 0x8000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/net.go:172 +0xe4
crypto/tls.(*block).readFromUntil(0xc820a35b00, 0x7f161f3005f8, 0xc8200242d8, 0x5, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/crypto/tls/conn.go:460 +0xcc
crypto/tls.(*Conn).readRecord(0xc820676600, 0x3e67e17, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/crypto/tls/conn.go:562 +0x2d1
crypto/tls.(*Conn).Read(0xc820676600, 0xc82072a000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/crypto/tls/conn.go:939 +0x167
net/http.noteEOFReader.Read(0x7f161f3006b0, 0xc820676600, 0xc820815c08, 0xc82072a000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1683 +0x67
net/http.(*noteEOFReader).Read(0xc82059b9c0, 0xc82072a000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0xc8208aa480, 0x0, 0x0)
    <autogenerated>:284 +0xd0
bufio.(*Reader).fill(0xc8207fc3c0)
    /usr/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:97 +0x1e9
bufio.(*Reader).ReadSlice(0xc8207fc3c0, 0xa, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:328 +0x21a
net/http/internal.readChunkLine(0xc8207fc3c0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/internal/chunked.go:110 +0x53
net/http/internal.(*chunkedReader).beginChunk(0xc8208aab70)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/internal/chunked.go:47 +0x39
net/http/internal.(*chunkedReader).Read(0xc8208aab70, 0xc820151c00, 0x200, 0x200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/internal/chunked.go:77 +0xb7
net/http.(*body).readLocked(0xc8208604c0, 0xc820151c00, 0x200, 0x200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transfer.go:651 +0xa1
net/http.(*body).Read(0xc8208604c0, 0xc820151c00, 0x200, 0x200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transfer.go:643 +0x110
net/http.(*bodyEOFSignal).Read(0xc820860500, 0xc820151c00, 0x200, 0x200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1609 +0x26a
encoding/json.(*Decoder).refill(0xc820392680, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/encoding/json/stream.go:152 +0x287
encoding/json.(*Decoder).readValue(0xc820392680, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/encoding/json/stream.go:128 +0x413
encoding/json.(*Decoder).Decode(0xc820392680, 0x275c5c0, 0xc820860540, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/encoding/json/stream.go:57 +0x159
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/watch/json.(*Decoder).Decode(0xc8208aaba0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/watch/json/decoder.go:50 +0xa5
k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/watch.(*StreamWatcher).receive(0xc8208aabd0)
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/watch/iowatcher.go:93 +0x104
created by k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/watch.NewStreamWatcher
    /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/Godeps/_workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/watch/iowatcher.go:60 +0xbf

goroutine 2238 [select]:
net/http.(*persistConn).writeLoop(0xc8207b11e0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1273 +0x472
created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:854 +0x10cb

goroutine 2237 [select]:
net/http.(*persistConn).readLoop(0xc8207b11e0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1178 +0xd52
created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:853 +0x10a6
```

Is this normal? Should we be concerned?

Comment: Can you look in the logs for the router and see if there is a message?  Generally you should not see a restart count in normal operation.

Comment: Hi @Clayton, the logs don't offer me any info - other than that the config is being reloaded frequently (presumably if services are updated or services are moved to different nodes). Logs look like this, repeated a bit:

`I0523 21:27:07.167033       1 router.go:310] Router reloaded:`
`- Checking HAProxy /healthz on port 1936 ...`
`- HAProxy port 1936 health check ok : 0 retry attempt(s).`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else getting this issue, I was able to track down this github issue where this is discussed (and a PR later submitted to fix): https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/8825